# Php 5.6.21 with Xdebug 2.4 is very slow

Tags: php, apache, xampp, xdebug

I have installed XAMPP on Windows 7 x64, and after installing xdebug 2.4, everything became slower (10X)
In php.ini I added:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0rc4-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\Tmp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
```

Comment: Well you have the profiler constantly running (it's the `profiler_enable` option). That's going to slow you down. And imo, you should set `remote_enable` to 1. There are browser extensions for Firefox and Chrome (and probably other browsers) that make it really easy to start and stop debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @terminus already pointed out you have `xdebug.profiler_enable` set to `true`, which means your profiler will run every time a PHP script is executed.

Taken from the [xdebug docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler):

> **xdebug.profiler_enable**
>   Type: integer, Default value: `0`
>   Enables Xdebug's profiler which creates files in the profile output directory. Those files can be read by KCacheGrind to visualize your data. This setting can not be set in your script with `ini_set()`. If you want to selectively enable the profiler, please set `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger` to `1` instead of using this setting.

To fix the main issue **disable** `xdebug.profiler_enable` and **enable** `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger`

After that you can run the profiler by passing the `XDEBUG_PROFILE` Parameter via HTTP:

```
curl 'http://localhost/?XDEBUG_PROFILE=1'
```

Or with the `xdebug.profiler_enable` option on the command line:

```
$ php -d xdebug.profiler_enable=On <yourphpscrip>.php
```

**Please Note:** that using X-Debug will always slow down the scripts execution time so never install X-Debug in a production environment.